# Swap nested list Python 3

Tags: list, python-3.x, nested

Having looked at the python 3 documentation I would like to attempt something similar

```
nested_list = [
(1,4,7,10),
(2,5,8,11),
(3,6,9,12),
]
sorted(nested_list, key=lambda nes: nes[0])

print(nested_list)
```

I would like the list to output as:

```
[(2, 5, 8, 11), (1, 4, 7, 10), (3, 6, 9, 12)]
```

But instead it outputs as:

```
[(1, 4, 7, 10), (2, 5, 8, 11), (3, 6, 9, 12)]
```

Which is the same!

I am using Python 3.5.1 btw.

Comment: Well yes, you sorted the list on the first element. And that's the right order. How should the lists be ordered instead?

Comment: what is the ordering criteria for your desired output? `sorted` is doing just that, sorting.

Comment: What was so hard to understand? TallChuck understood it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'key' argument takes a function, and that function is passed each element of the array as an argument as it iterates through. The line

```
sorted(nested_list, key=lambda nes: nes[0])
```

looks at each tuple in `nested_list`, assigns it to `nes` and sorts it by `nes[0]`. If you wanted to sort it based on something else, say the last index of each array, you would change it to

```
sorted(nested_list, key=lambda nes: nes[-1])
```

If all you want to do is swap the first two tuples of `nested_list`, I would suggest simply saying

```
nested_list[0], nested_list[1] = nested_list[1], nested_list[0]
```

Comment: Thanks for that! It worked!!! turns out I just wanted to swap the first two tuples haha

Comment: if I try it with strings it doesn't work, I get a type error?

Comment: what command did you use?

Comment: It worked when I did nested_list[0], nested_list[1] = nested_list[1], nested_list[0] for the integers. When I made them strings it didn't work.

Comment: The command works for me on strings, I would suggest you check your assumptions, make sure the list contains what you expect, or that you didn't mistype something somewhere.

Comment: ok I will check, thanks for your answer, will marked as accepted :)